# How to remove bad smell from fridge and refrigerator?

Tags: food-science, smell

How to remove bad smell of food from fridge and refrigerator?

Comment: That other question (How to get rid of the smell from the fridge?) was really about how to avoid getting bad smells in your fridge to begin with (despite the incorrect title), and the answers addressed that issue. This question is different: how to get rid of the smell once it is in there.

Comment: My experience -- as long as the offending items (mold, garlic, rotten beans, ...etc.) are gone, and the fridge is clean, plugged in and operating, the smell will go away by itself. Sometimes it will take a while, ... like *months* in the case of a refrigerator which had been left unplugged for years and had acquired a mildew smell, but we cleaned it well, and learned to live with the smell ... until one day we realized, "hey that stink is gone!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you access the evaporator coils of the fridge, and where the condensate goes?  A frequent problem is that these are covered up or difficult to access.  If stuff gets spilled or otherwise get into these inaccessible areas, it can take a very long time to dissipate.  Get out your screwdriver.